# C# WPF OxyPlot error plot does not exist in namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Hi I have a problem configuring oxyplot in WPF. I have found a few solutions but nothing works. I have found out that this is the best http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/03/creating-graphs-in-wpf-using-oxyplot/
but something still wrong and I get this error in XAML file:

the name plot does not exist in the namespace codeplex

MainWindow.xaml FILE:

```
<Window x:Class="OxyPlotDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OxyPlotDemo"
     xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.codeplex.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <oxy:Plot x:Name="Plot1" Title="A Graph" Model="{Binding PlotModel}" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1">
    </oxy:Plot>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
namespace OxyPlotDemo

{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private ViewModels.MainWindowModel viewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {

        viewModel = new ViewModels.MainWindowModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

MainWindowModel.cs

```
using  System.ComponentModel;
using OxyPlot;


namespace OxyPlotDemo.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private PlotModel plotModel;
        public PlotModel PlotModel
        {
            get { return plotModel; }
            set { plotModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("PlotModel"); }
    }

    public MainWindowModel()
    {
        PlotModel = new PlotModel();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}
```

Maybe someone has better solution. I just need to display a few charts, that contains a lot of data from sensors, not in real time.

Comment: Try using `xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"`

Comment: @Kirenenko i tried it and when i do this error appear also in XAML but it's write : The member "Mode" is not recognized or is not accesible

Comment: Maybe you have writen "Mode" instead of "Model" in some part of your code?

Comment: @Kirenenko sorry i make mistake in writing, error contains word Model not Mode

Comment: Use `<oxy:PlotView` instead of `<oxy:Plot`

Comment: @Kirenenko i do this and now its's write The property "Title" was now found in type 'PlotView'. When i delete this title it's ok but later when i add method SetUpModel from toutorial appear error DataTimeAxis does not contain constructor which has 3parameters.

Comment: Meybe this toutorial is not very well, but i can't find something better which is working

Comment: This is a basic tutorial from the official page http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-wpf.html#create-project. Just bind the PlotModel to the PlotView Model property, and edit all the properties you want on the ViewModel.

Answer (score 5):

I've had a same issue with OxyPlot lib from NuGet, when migrating from lib version 1.x to 2.1.
SO i found, that in version 2.1 `Plot` class is moved to [another library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OxyPlot.Contrib.Wpf/), see releases history at [their github page](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/releases).
That worked for me:

`xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"`

`xmlns:oxycontrols="http://oxyplot.org/wpf/contrib"`

`<oxycontrols:Plot .../>`

Answer (score 3):

```
<Window x:Class="Universal_trc_csvParser.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Universal_trc_csvParser"
        xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>


    <Grid>
        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding MyModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
    public MainViewModel()
        {
        this.MyModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Example 1" };
        this.MyModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(Math.Cos, 0, 10, 0.1, "cos(x)"));
        }

    public PlotModel MyModel { get; private set; }
    }
```

> This worked for me.

Comment: This works for brand new oxyplot 2.1.0, all other documents are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
So what i did was downgrade my "OxyPlot.Wpf" to version 1.0.0. and the example you speak of works fine, without the error "the name plot does not exist in the namespace".

```
 <oxy:Plot x:Name="Plot1" Title="A Graph" Model="{Binding PlotModel}" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1">
    </oxy:Plot>
```